# Using Select2 in dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, razor

Can't seem to get select2 working correctly in my view.

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "ResourceID"
    , null
    , "--Select--"
    , new {@class="input-control" ,data_role="select" })
```

If I use select2 outside of the DropDownList then it works so I know it's not a jquery or select2 issue.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZH7kZR

Comment: any console errors you are getting?

Comment: No errors and inspecting the element, the tags are there correctly.

Comment: Can you post an image of how it is being displayed now?

Comment: Displayed as a standard dropdownlist. I can provide a screenshot if needed.

Comment: Are options provided for dropdownlist? Or try creating a fiddle **[here](https://dotnetfiddle.net)**

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZH7kZR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.. So I think you have been missing `select2 css` and the initialization of `select2` on `select` element wasn't there in the fiddle you created. May be oversight. But do not forget to include proper `css` and `js` for `select2`.

Here is the **[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GWqF1L)** which is working fine and below are the `cdn urls` to get the file:

[**CSS**](http:////cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css) and **[JS](http:////cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js)**

Comment: css oversite but yes I forgot to initialize it